# How to add a new row exactly the same but change one value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to update a dataframe by adding one row, but changing a single value of it. Currently I am looping through days, but the value isn't changing. I have below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv",parse_dates = ["start_date","end_date"])
data["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["end_date"])
data["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["start_date"])

for i in range(0,14):
    changedate = pd.to_datetime((datetime.date.today()))
    changedate = changedate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    today = pd.to_datetime((datetime.date.today())) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    next_day = changedate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    if changedate.weekday() == 5 or changedate.weekday() ==6:
        continue
    if 1 < i < 7:
        new_data = data.loc[((data["name"] == ['certain_name']) & (data["start_date"] == today))]
        new_data["start_date"] = changedate
        new_data["end_date"] = next_day
        new_data["value_to_change"] = new_data["value_to_change"] * 0.75
        data = data.append(new_data, ignore_index = True)
    for index, rows in data.iterrows():
        if rows["start_date"] <= changedate and (pd.isnull(rows["end_date"]) or rows["end_date"] > changedate):
            date = pd.to_datetime('today')
            date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
            date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            data.loc[index, date] = 1

data.to_csv("myfile.csv")
```

So I would start with a dataframe like this:

```
   start_date    end_date          name  value_to_change
0  30/05/2022  31/05/2022  certain_name              100
1  31/05/2022  01/05/2022    other name              500
```

And ideally I want this:

```
   start_date    end_date          name  value_to_change  30/05/2022  31/05/2022  01/06/2022
0  30/05/2022  31/05/2022  certain_name              100         1.0         NaN         NaN
1  31/05/2022  01/07/2022    other name              500         1.0         1.0         1.0
2  31/05/2022  01/06/2022  certain_name               75         NaN         1.0         NaN
3  01/06/2022  02/06/2022  certain_name               75         NaN         NaN         1.0
4  02/06/2022  03/06/2022  certain_name               75         NaN         NaN         NaN
5  03/06/2022  04/06/2022  certain_name               75         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Continued for a number of dates so later on I can replace some 1.0's with the `value_to_change`.
I can see that the value to change isn't changing at all and furthermore a 1 is being added on todays date in all new columns.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: show your dataframe and your desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = df.start_date
df['Value'] = df.value_to_change
output = df.pivot(columns='Date', index=['start_date','end_date', 'name', 'Value'])
output = output.droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
   start_date    end_date          name  Value  30/05/2022  31/05/2022
0  30/05/2022  31/05/2022  certain_name    100       100.0         NaN
1  31/05/2022  01/05/2022    other name    500         NaN       500.0
```